# Finding the shap of the volume $\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{1} \left(\rho^2 \sin \phi \right) d \rho d \phi d \theta$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> I need to find the shap of the volume:$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{1} \left(\rho^2 \sin \phi \right) \,\mathrm d \rho \,\mathrm d \phi\,\mathrm d \theta$$

I thought that the shape is something like this: (the dark red) the height is $\pi/2$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:  $\rho^2 \sin \theta d\rho d\phi d\theta$ is the [volume element in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates).

So the volume is the volume of a part of a sphere as noted in OP, but not a half-sphere.

The limits of integrations are: $0\le \rho \le 1$  (this means that the sphere has radius $1$) and $0\le \phi \le \pi/2$,$0\le \theta \le \pi/2$ and this means that we have only one quarter of the half-sphere in the figure, the part limited by the planes $xz$ and $yz$.

[image]

Comment: $x$ - red, $y$-green, $z$ - blue.

Comment: Added a figure.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  & D=\{(x,y,z)|{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}}\le 1\,,x,y,z\ge 0\} \\ 
 & V=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-{{y}^{2}}}}{\int_{0}^{1-\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}}{dzdydx}}}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\int_{0}^{1}{\rho {{\sin }^{2}}\phi \,\,d\rho }d\phi }d\theta } \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: I asked for the shape, but never mind +1

Comment: sorry I determinate region

Comment: what is  your software?

Comment: Geogebra$~~~~~~$

Comment: nice figure....